# Syntax highlighting should use the correct language mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, syntax-highlighting

Version 0.1.64.

On the main site, the syntax highlighting mode depends on the tags that are active on a question, so a [lisp] or [scheme] question would activate Lisp highlighting mode by default. The Android app doesn't do that.

[image: Screenshot]

Notice how the highlighting has gone off the rails after encountering the `#` (which is not a comment character in Lisp).

Comment: Link to the answer shown: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19993142

Comment: It does have a [lisp] tag though, which should be sufficient (lisp and scheme both dispatch to the same highlighting mode, on the site). In any case, this affects other questions tagged [scheme] also.

Comment: Ah, the Google prettify support for Lisp and Scheme doesn't distinguish between them.

Comment: If I insert `<!-- language: lang-scheme -->` into the post for both snippets, the highlighting from Google Prettifier makes the same wrong parsing choices; it indeed appears that in the Android client the highlighting language is guessed at by Google Prettify rather than use the tags on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android app, as of version 1.0.32, *finally* uses the tags to show current snytax highlighting. It doesn't work 100% of the time yet, for example a [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) tag [won't get Python syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230530/python-syntax-highlighting-isnt-working-quite-right-on-the-android-app) at the moment, but the big use cases work.

Comment: Cool, that's good news! The tags used in my linked post still don't work, but I'll be happy to tick this answer once that works. Thanks for all your hard work.

Comment: Confirmed working as of 1.0.33.