# Python syntax highlighting isn't working quite right on the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, syntax-highlighting

Using version 1.0.31 of the Android app, when I look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298855/beautiful-soup-and-frames-iframes-extract/23299318#23299318), what I see is this:

[image]

The syntax highlighter does not appear to be parsing [Python's triple-quoted string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) correctly (`foo` and `bar` in the first code block should be green, like the rest of the string). It works fine on the desktop site, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.0.32 questions and answers like the one linked will show up correctly. Here's what this case looks like:

[image]